# ios create a modal custom segue

Tags: ios, segue

hi i'm trying to create a custom modal segue that slides the src view controller to right which reveals destination view controller behind it. any ideas on how i can acheive it

so far i have tried this but it's not working.

```
#import "CustomMenuSegue.h"

@implementation CustomMenuSegue

- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.2 options:UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController modalTransitionStyle:dst animated:YES];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];

}


@end
```